# What is the equivalent of causality in Euclidean field theory?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, causality, unitarity, wick-rotation

In Wick rotated quantum field theory where $t$ becomes $it$ and it has Euclidean metric signature. What would be the equivalent statement that events outside each others light-cones are disconnected by causality? i.e. operators outside the lightcone commute.

e.g. In topological field theory is there some condition that take the place of causality?

I would guess this is related to the fact that QFT needs to be "Unitary" in which case, Euclidean field theory needs to be.....?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The property corresponding to Minkowskian unitarity is *reflection positivity* in the Osterwalder-Schrader axioms for a Euclidean field theory, see for instance chapter 6.1 of Glimm and Jaffe's *Quantum Physics*.

One formulation of reflection positivity means that for all tuples of real Schwartz functions $f_i$ the partition functions $Z_{ij} = Z[f_i - \theta f_j]$ form a positive matrix, where $\theta$ is the action of reflection $t\mapsto -t$ on functions.

Comment: The $f_i$ must be supported on (e.g.) $t<0$, I believe. Also, it may be hidden in your notation, but each $f_i$ should represent products of multiple smeared insertions, if I understand your intention. Also the terms you wrote as ($f_i-\Theta f_j$) should be more like a product?

Comment: The lightcone causality in Minkowski requires not just unitary but also Poincare invariance, which follows from the Euclidean isometry invariance of the Euclidean theory. So the latter is important also.

Comment: @EmmyNoether I have really just written there what Glimm/Jaffe write. You're probably thinking of the other variant that is $\langle \theta A,A\rangle\geq 0$ where the $A$ is something like a vertex operator functional that's supported only on $t>0$, which they say is equivalent to what I wrote here.

Comment: Thanks -- I see you're referring instead to Glimm+Jaffe 6.1.9, $M_{ij}=S\{f_i-\Theta f_j\}$, with your $Z \sim M$. That uses def'n 6.1.4, $S\{f\}=\int e^{i\phi(f)} d\mu$.  In that case, I would have guessed we should take $M_{ij}=S\{i f_i + i\Theta f_j\} = \int e^{-\phi(f_i + \Theta f_j)} d\mu $, because now that looks like the path integral definition of reflection positivity.  Can you make sense of it?

Comment: Thanks, I think I will have to take some time to understand what this all means!